# Prove that the sum of two continuous functions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow a} f(x)+g(x) = f(a)+g(a)$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$ when $0<|x-a|< \delta_f $ and $|g(x)-g(a)|< \epsilon$ $\ $ when $0<|x-a|< \delta_g$

Let  $\delta_h$ be defined as $\min(\delta_g ,\delta_f)$ and $h(x)$ be defined as $f(x)+g(x)$

$$\ |f(x)-f(a)|+|g(x)-g(a)|< 2\epsilon\tag{1}$$

$$\ |f(x)-f(a) + g(x)-g(a)|< 2\epsilon$$

$$\ |h(x)-h(a)|< 2\epsilon$$

We can replace $\delta_f$  and  $\delta_g$ by
$_h$ to get

$|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$ when $0<|x-a|<\delta_h$ and $\ |g(x)-g(a)|< \epsilon$ when $0<|x-a|<\delta_h$

Since (1) is true when $0<|x-a|<\delta_h$, we can find a $\delta_h$ for every value of $2ε$

for every $2\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x−a|<\delta\implies ∣h(x)−h(a)∣<2\epsilon$ and for every $2\epsilon$ there exists an $\epsilon$ so for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$.

Is the proof logically correct and is it worded correctly?

Comment: Could use some cleaning up. Would be nice to see the triangle inequality and adding up $\varepsilon/2$ twice to get $\varepsilon$.

Comment: You should probably note explicitly that if you use $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ as value interval for both $f$ and $g$ (and, consequently, minimal $\delta$ of the both), then their sum is at most $\varepsilon$ from its limit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is quite good, but not totally correct. You should be aiming at the inequality$$|h(x)-h(a)|<\varepsilon.\tag1$$So, your numbers $\delta_f$ and $\delta_g$ should be such that$$|x-a|<\delta_f\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\frac\varepsilon2$$and that$$|x-a|<\delta_g\implies|g(x)-g(a)|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$Then, yes, if you take $\delta=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$ and if $|x-a|<\delta$, $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Since I can get a delta to satisfy the criteria for 2ε, I can get a delta to satisfy the criteria for ε. Is it incomplete if I write this?

Comment: @ArjunNigam Then you should add that observation to your proof, that is, you should have added that if you can do it with $2\varepsilon$, then you can do it with $\varepsilon$ too.

Comment: just out of curiosity though, how do I get an appropriate delta for which $$|x-a|<\delta_f\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\frac\varepsilon2\text{ and }|x-a|<\delta_g\implies|g(x)-g(a)|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$

Comment: @ArjunNigam For each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. Since $\frac\varepsilon2>0$...

Comment: I'd appreciate if you would verify my formal way of saying that a delta exists for ε if it exists for 2ε before I edit it in. We can define $\  _h$ as some function of 2ε say $\  _h$ =p(2ε). For every real value of 2ε,  $\  _h$ would be real. If 2ε is real, then ε would also be real. Define =p(ε) and since the function returns real values for all real numbers, it would return a real value for ε. Thus a  would exist for all positive ε.

Comment: @ArjunNigam **No.** Don't think in terms of functions. Take $\varepsilon>0$. You know that for every $r>0$ ther is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(a)\bigr|<2r$. Then take $r=\frac\varepsilon2$ and you're done.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit that in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76496/discussion-between-arjun-nigam-and-jose-carlos-santos).